# How to make a TextBox have focus so user can start typing

Tags: xaml

I have a `TextBox` which I would like to have the focus when the 'view' loads. When I say focus, I mean that the user can start typing straight away and text appears in the focused TextBox.

I've seen so many questions similar here on SO, and they pretty much all have the same answer which is use Dependency Property: `FocusManager.FocusedElement`

The issue I have is, whilst this does select the control, it doesn't allow the user to type! Normally when you select a TextBlock you get a blinking caret. Using the following, I see a non-blinking caret and I cannot enter text without selecting the `textbox` (which defeats the point)

```
<TextBox Margin="10" 
         Text="{Binding Threshold,   
         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,                             
         ValidatesOnDataErrors=True }"                            
         FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the declaration to the MainContainer in your XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="MainContainer"
      FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=txtbox}"
      ...
      >
    ...
    <TextBox    Grid.Row="..." Grid.Column="..." 
                x:Name="txtbox">
    </TextBox>
    ...
</Grid>
```

Comment: This does fix it, +1, if you can explain why I'll mark as answer :)